# Show all videos by tag name

Tags: tags, get-posts, terms

I need to get all videos by tag name, im using code like that

```
$tax_terms = get_terms('media_category', 'orderby=count&order=DESC&hide_empty=0');

foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {

$posts = get_posts(array(
                "meta_key" => 'select', 
                "meta_value" => 1,
                "post_mime_type" => "video",
                "taxonomy" => $tax_term->taxonomy,
                "term" => $tax_term->slug,
                "numberposts" => 100, 
                "posts_per_page" => 100));
?>
```

But that query dont returns any elements, what's the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. 
Use for tag_id in get_posts.

```
$tax_terms = get_terms('media_category', 'orderby=count&order=DESC&hide_empty=0');

foreach ( $tax_terms as $tax_term ) {

$posts = get_posts(array(
                "meta_key" => 'select', 
                "meta_value" => 1,
                "tag_id" => 5,
                "post_mime_type" => "video",
                "taxonomy" => $tax_term->taxonomy,
                "term" => $tax_term->slug,
                "numberposts" => 100, 
                "posts_per_page" => 100));
```